# Visual Studio not finding cl.exe

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I just installed and configure VS for Windows 10 using the online instructions but when I try to run the sample program, I get an error that cl.exe cant be found. The executable exists in the defined compiler path. If I copy the full path and paste it in a command window, it runs.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the IDE or command prompt?  For the command prompt to work you usually need to run the "Developer Command Prompt"s to get the environment variables set up for compilation and linking.

Comment: I am using IDE. I launched it from a command prompt with administrator priveledges because it wasn't saving the initial configuration settings. Now, If I launch it from the developer command prompt for vs, I get a different error - cannot open program database vc140.pdb.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the VCVARSALL.BAT to configure the environment??
I suggest you copy/set all this config variables in Control Panel | System | System | Advanced Config | Environment Variables
Or create a .reg file with this configuration and double-click it...
Bye...